# Прошу помощи с составлением условия IF ELSE на PHP

Tags: php

Всем привет. Хоть в php я немного разбираюсь, но составить одно условие не могу.

Имеется переменная `$name` которую хранит рандомные значения, на основе которой я создаю ссылку (через `echo`)

`<a href='/artist/".$name."'>".$name."</a>`

Когда в переменной хранится одно имя, например `Adel`, то все нормально, ссылка формируется правильная `<a href='/artist/Adel'>Adel</a>`

Но если в переменной несколько имен например `Adel feat. Cher feat. 1GN` то перейти по ссылке `<a href='/artist/Adel feat. Cher feat. 1GN'>Adel feat. Cher feat. 1GN</a>` не выйдет.

Теперь переходим к самой задаче, как сделать условие IF ELSE, что бы перед созданием ссылки шла проверка. Если в переменной встречаются названия с `feat.` то сделать несколько ссілок. 1 ссылка - до feat., вторая - после и т.д.

Что бы получилось на подобии:

`<a href='/artist/Adel'>Adel</a> feat. <a href='/artist/Cher'>Cher</a> feat. <a href='/artist/1GN'>1GN</a>`

Целый день ломаю голову...
Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь!!

Comment: `explode()` и цикл вывода вам в помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверь строку `$name` на наличие в ней слова `" feat. "`

```
if(preg_match(" feat. ", $name)) {
    $namesArr = array();
    //если нашлось
    $names = explode(" feat. ", $name);//то разбиваешь слова на массив
    foreach($names as $val) {
        $namesArr[] = "<a href=\"/artist/{$val}\">{$val}</a>";
    }
    echo implode(" feat. ", $namesArr); // собираем строку взад
} else {
    echo "<a href=\"/artist/{$name}\">{$name}</a>";
}
```

Comment: можно и без проверки. Если нет вхождения, то explode вернет массив содержащий исходную строку. которая также выведется с помощью единственной итерации цикла

Comment: Как-то вы криво строку проверяете на наличие подстроки `Warning:  preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in ...`

Comment: супер, все работает! вот только, в `preg_match` искомое слово нужно писать не `feat.` а `/feat./`